# Improve python code with many if statements

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

I've seen a code on a project and would like to know how to write a code with less statements.

Here is the code:

```
    if not self.test_done:
        phase = "Test"
    else:
        if self.need_video and not self.video_sent:
            phase = 'Video'
        else:
            if not self.screening1_made and not self.screening2_made:
                phase = 'Screening 1'
            else:
                if ( self.screening1_made and not self.screening2_made ) or not self.passed_screening:
                    phase = 'Screening 2'
                else:
                    if not self.passed_phase1:
                        phase = 'Interview 1'
                    else:
                        if not self.passed_phase2:
                            phase = 'Interview 2'
                        else:
                            if not self.passed_phase3:
                                phase = 'Interview 3'
                            else:
                                if not self.got_offer:
                                    phase = 'Waiting offer decision'
                                else:
                                    if self.accepted_offer is None:
                                        phase = 'Waiting decision from candidate'
                                    elif self.accepted_offer == "Accepted":
                                        phase = 'Accepted offer'
                                    elif self.accepted_offer == "Declined":
                                        phase = 'Declined offer'
```

What would be best practices to avoid nested if statements?

Comment: Use a dictionary.

Comment: You can fix the deep nesting with `elif`s instead of most of the `if`s. Since you're testing different conditions on all of those tests, I'm  not sure there's going to be any good way to avoid them.

Comment: Not a dictionary (or any sort of mapping for that matter), these conditions don't make good keys.

Answer (score 4):

You can extract it to the method and early return, also you can use a dictionary lookup to get your output.

```py
OFFER = {
    None: "Waiting decision from candidate",
    "Accepted": "Accepted offer",
    "Declined": "Declined offer",
}


def some_function_name(self):
    if not self.test_done:
        return "Test"

    if self.need_video and not self.video_sent:
        return "Video"

    if not self.screening1_made and not self.screening2_made:
        return "Screening 1"

    if (self.screening1_made and not self.screening2_made) or not self.passed_screening:
        return "Screening 2"
    if not self.passed_phase1:
        return "Interview 1"
    if not self.passed_phase2:
        return "Interview 2"
    if not self.passed_phase3:
        return "Interview 3"
    if not self.got_offer:
        return "Waiting offer decision"

    return OFFER.get(self.accepted_offer, None)
```

Answer (score 1):

This smells to me like a state machine. A "switch - case" construct is often used when evaluating state machines, and while python doesn't currently have that exact feature yet (3.10 will introduce `match: case`), A list of `elif`'s should do the trick just fine:

```
if not self.test_done:
    phase = "Test"
elif self.need_video and not self.video_sent:
    phase = 'Video'
elif self.need_video and not self.video_sent:
    phase = 'Video'
elif not self.screening1_made and not self.screening2_made:
    phase = 'Screening 1'
elif ( self.screening1_made and not self.screening2_made ) or not self.passed_screening:
    phase = 'Screening 2'
elif not self.passed_phase1:
    phase = 'Interview 1'
elif not self.passed_phase2:
    phase = 'Interview 2'
elif not self.passed_phase3:
    phase = 'Interview 3'
elif not self.got_offer:
    phase = 'Waiting offer decision'
elif self.accepted_offer is None:
    phase = 'Waiting decision from candidate'
elif self.accepted_offer == "Accepted":
    phase = 'Accepted offer'
elif self.accepted_offer == "Declined":
    phase = 'Declined offer
```

flattened it's not so bad to look at, and you probably won't find a significantly more elegant solution without changing how you track all the conditionals.

Answer (score 1):

You should refactor your program.  Here's a rough Interview class and related objects, which includes a basic dictionary for event names and number of rounds.

```
class InterviewEvent:
    def __init__(self, event_id, event_name, total_rounds) -> None:
        self.event_id: int = event_id
        self.event_name: str = event_name
        self.total_rounds: int = total_rounds
        self.competed_rounds: int = 0
        self.completed: bool = False

class Interview:
    """Interview class to track interview progress.
    """
    def __init__(self, expected_workflow: dict = None):
        self.events = []
        self.current_event: InterviewEvent = None
        if expected_workflow:
            self.__init_events(expected_workflow)

    def __init_events(self, wf: dict) -> None:
        """Populate events list from workflow dictionary."""
        self.events = [InterviewEvent(i, k, v) for i, (k, v) in enumerate(wf.items())]
        # Set current event
        self.current_event = self.events[0]

    def completed_event_round(self, title, round_number):
        """Update round number for event.  If complete, increment
        to next round or next event in workflow.
        """
        for event in self.events:
            if event.event_name.lower() == title.lower():
                if event.competed_rounds < round_number:
                    event.competed_rounds = round_number
                
                # Mark event completed if completed rounds equals total rounds.
                if event.competed_rounds == event.total_rounds:
                    event.completed = True

                if event.completed:
                    # Increment current event by 1.
                    self.current_event = self.events[event.event_id + 1]
    
    def __event_attrs(self, e: InterviewEvent) -> str:
        return "\n".join([f"{k}: {v}" for k, v in e.__dict__.items()])

    @property
    def view_current(self):
        print(self.__event_attrs(self.current_event))

    @property
    def remaining_events(self):
        return [e for e in self.events if not e.completed]

    @property
    def view_remaining_events(self):
        events_remaining = self.remaining_events
        if events_remaining:
            print("\n\n".join([self.__event_attrs(e) for e in events_remaining]))

    @property
    def event_ids(self):
        """Return all current event IDs."""
        return [e.event_id for e in self.events]

    @property
    def event_names(self):
        """Return all current event names."""
        return [e.event_name for e in self.events]


# Dictionary of event names and number of rounds.
workflow_rounds = dict(
    Test = 1,
    Video = 1,
    Screening = 2,
    Interview = 3,
)
```

View events that are not complete.

```
interview.view_remaining_events
```

Output:

```
event_id: 0
event_name: Test
total_rounds: 1
competed_rounds: 0
completed: False

event_id: 1
event_name: Video
total_rounds: 1
competed_rounds: 0
completed: False

event_id: 2
event_name: Screening
total_rounds: 2
competed_rounds: 0
completed: False

event_id: 3
event_name: Interview
total_rounds: 3
competed_rounds: 0
completed: False
```

View current event

```
interview.view_current
```

Output:

```
    event_id: 0
    event_name: Test
    total_rounds: 1
    competed_rounds: 0
    completed: False
```

Mark first Test round as complete

```
interview.completed_event_round(title = "Test", round_number = 1)
```

Again, view events that are not complete.

```
interview.view_remaining_events
```

Output:

```
event_id: 1
event_name: Video
total_rounds: 1
competed_rounds: 0
completed: False

event_id: 2
event_name: Screening
total_rounds: 2
competed_rounds: 0
completed: False

event_id: 3
event_name: Interview
total_rounds: 3
competed_rounds: 0
completed: False
```

Finally, view current event

```
interview.view_current
```

Output:

```
    event_id: 1
    event_name: Video
    total_rounds: 1
    competed_rounds: 0
    completed: False
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea Mark! I'm new about Python and still learning it.
Mark, the question received some downvotes for being unclear, low effort or not useful or all of them. Why does this question was downvoted?

Answer (score 0):

You can use lambda to run expressions. In the example below, we itterate through the list of tuples, containing lambda expressions and strings. When we find a lambda expression that is true, we break out of the loop.

```
x = 1

expressions = [
    (lambda: x == 0, 'X is equal to 0'),
    (lambda: x == 1, 'X is equal to 1'),
    (lambda: x == 2, 'X is equal to 2'),
]

phrase = 'No result found'

for item in expressions:
    expression = item[0]
    text = item[1]

    if expression():
        phrase = text
        break


print(phrase)
```

This is the result.

```
X is equal to 1
```